# SSRS Display static rows on multiple pages for 2 different groups

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I'm trying to repeat 2 separate rows on every page of a report. The first is the reports title which lists the document details (in this case sales order details) and the second displays the line items associated with the document.

As multiple documents can be selected, I've built the report with 2 groups:

[Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liLcH.png)

The customer order group displays all shipping and billing information which I want displayed once per order (working properly), and the LineNumber group displays the details of the order. Basically, I'd like to display the top row of each group on each page so that you can see the Order number and the details column headers.

Currently, only the sales order header line is repeating.

I've turned on the "Repeat Header Rows on each page" in the Tablix properties and I've toggled the "KeepWithGroup" to After and the "RepeatOnNewPage" to True in the Static row group of the Advanced Mode but I can't get it to repeat the details header.